# Parse multipart/form-data response in rust / reqwest

Tags: pdf, rust, multipartform-data, reqwest

I'm relatively new to rust and using `reqwest` to fetch a PDF document from a REST API endpoint. The content-type of the **response** is `multipart/form-data; boundary=bc1f6465-6738-4b46-9d9d-b9ae36afa8cb` with two parts:

```
--bc1f6465-6738-4b46-9d9d-b9ae36afa8cb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"
Content-Type: application/json

{"documentId":"QkNfRENfSUwwMDEsRTA1OEU3ODQtMDAwMC1DNzY5LTg1MjktMTRFRkI5RTBFNjRF"}
--bc1f6465-6738-4b46-9d9d-b9ae36afa8cb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"; filename=document.pdf
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.4
<binary content>
%%EOF

--bc1f6465-6738-4b46-9d9d-b9ae36afa8cb--
```

I want now to save the PDF document in the 2nd part as a valid PDF file on disk. But the multipart functionality within `reqwest` seems to create new multipart **requests** whereas I need to parse a multipart **response**.

My code to download the file:

```
use reqwest::{self, header::AUTHORIZATION};
fn main() {
    let url = "https://example.com/rest/document/123";
    let authorization_header = String::from("Bearer ") + access_token.as_str();
    let res = client.get(url)
        .header(AUTHORIZATION, &authorization_header)
        .send()
        .expect("Error calling API");
}
```

Any hint on how to process the multipart/form-data response is appreciated!